# How to overwrite Django app to Pythonanywhere? 3

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

After the second time deploying the Django app to Pythonanywhere, (I re-edited and overwritten in VS code and did git push) I got the following error.

The command is

```
pa_autoconfigure_django.py https://github.com/[user_name]/[project_name].git --nuke
```

Is that something exceeded?

What should I delete? I don't know what wrong it is...

```
Downloading llvmlite-0.33.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (18.3 MB)
     |███████████████████████████▍    | 15.7 MB 14.7 MB/s eta 0:00:01ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hogehoge/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 47, in <module>
    main(arguments['<git-repo-url>'], arguments['--domain'], arguments['--python'], nuke=arguments.get('--nuke'))
  File "/home/hogehoge/.local/bin/pa_autoconfigure_django.py", line 31, in main
    project.create_virtualenv(nuke=nuke)
  File "/home/hogehoge/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pythonanywhere/django_project.py", line 29, in create_virtualenv
    self.virtualenv.pip_install(packages)
  File "/home/hogehoge/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pythonanywhere/virtualenvs.py", line 28, in pip_install
    subprocess.check_call(commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/home/hogehoge/.virtualenvs/hogehoge.pythonanywhere.com/bin/pip', 'install', '-r', '/home/hogehoge.pythonanywhere.com/requirements.txt']' returned non-zero ex
it status 1.
```

Comment: [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded

Comment: I should upgrade plan? or delete somethings? If so what should I delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your disk quota is exceeded.

One solution is to upgrade your PythonAnywhere account, but you could also try to reduce your disk space usage.

In a Bash console use the `du` ("disk-usage") to find out how much space is being used in various places in your file storage:

`du -hs /tmp ~/.[!.]* ~/* | sort -h`

The files in `/tmp/` are the most common cause of an unexpected quota max-out. It's usually safe to just delete them all:

`rm -rf /tmp/*`

You can also clean up any old, unused virtualenvs with `rmvirtualenv my-old-venv-name`.

Comment: Thank you. I edit requirements.tx file and recreate app in pythonanywhere, I succeeded.